# Chaining OR conditions in EF 5.0

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I will preface this with I'm actively searching for the solution to this problem but figured I might short cut some research and development time if someone here on stack has already figured this out.  (I have found nothing online so here goes)

We have a case in an application framework we are building where we need the capability to take in a set of Predicates (`List<Expression<Func<T,bool>>>`) and parse it in a search framework.

Right now we have the capability to filter in this way being that:

```
//Assume predicates is passed as a method argument.
//     of List<Expression<Func<T,bool>>>
//Assume user is passed in as a method argument.
//Assume FilterToUserAccess is a custom extension method that restricts the dataset
//    to access restrictions.
var query = _dbContext.Set<EntityType>()
     .FilterToUserAccess(user);
foreach(var p in predicates){
     query = query.Where(p);
}

return p.ToList();
```

The reason we need to do this is for scale-ability of filterable objects.  However for a quick search this is not possible given the built in capabilities of EF.  What I need to be able to do is:

Object A (lets pretend it's a race car) and we want to search make, model, team, and driver in a quick search box.  So if I enter "Earnhardt", it would search all race car entity properties being make, model, team, and driver.  I would end up with all the DEI cars as well as Dale Jr.  I would like to use the same approach so we can configure a searchable entity and reflect the search configuration on application start.  I would ideally like to make some way of having the query look similar to this:

```
//Assume predicates is passed as a method argument.
//     of List<Expression<Func<T,bool>>>
//Assume user is passed in as a method argument.
//Assume FilterToUserAccess is a custom extension method that restricts the dataset
//    to access restrictions.
var query = _dbContext.Set<EntityType>()
    .FilterToUserAccess(user);
foreach(var p in predicates){
    query = query.Or(p);
}

return p.ToList();
```

I realize I can do:

```
_dbContext.Set<EntityType>().Where(predicate1 || predicate2 || predicate3)
```

However this will not work for the approach we want to take to solve this problem.  Ideally an admin for one of our client sites would be able to go in and configure an additional search term with a single click to be included in any and all quick searches for that entity type like we can currently pull off with Filters which use the standard `.Where(...)` "and" chaining logic.

Comment: You will need to build an expression tree dynamically.

Comment: Any possible starting places for this?  I know the basics of hand generating an expression tree but I fear this rabbit hole goes pretty deep really quick.  Any references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might check out LinqKit/Expression Builder. EB works for EF and makes it pretty easy to chain `OR` conditions.

Comment: LinqKit was exactly what I needed.  Bump for the point in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First solution was a bust, however with some more digging there is an incredibly simple solution, verified and works.

**Step 1:** install the NuGet package for LinqKit.

**Step 2:** Enjoy the code below

```
using (ISampleRepository repo = new SampleRepository())
{
    var predicates = new List<Expression<Func<Customer,bool>>>(){
        (x => x.FirstName.Contains(searchValue)),
        (x => x.LastName.Contains(searchValue))
    };

    var lambda = PredicateBuilder.False<Customer>();
    lambda = predicates.Aggregate(lambda, (current, p) => current.Or(p).Expand());

    var query = repo.QueryCustomers().AsExpandable().Include(x => x.Phones).Where(lambda);
    return query.Take(500)
        .ToList()
        .Select(x => x.ToDTO())
        .ToList();
}
```

This is just the spike sample but doing the same thing with a method taking in ->

```
List<T> QuickSearch<T>(string input) ...
```

Will be able to use the same approach.  You have a collection of predicates still in Expression form passed in, then you use the predicate builder tricks to pull the query off.  Then using the AsExpandable() allows you to execute the combined predicate created using the predicate builder.

Hopefully this is helpful to more than just me, but this is the solution I'm going with as it's quite a bit less code.  Allows you to build your predicates elsewhere... and still combine them in an "OR" statement after the fact.

Comment: Have you tried this against an in memory queryable yet?  I'd be concerned that the parameter expression would not stay in scope between each expression.

Comment: In the process of testing as we speak.  The parameter expressions use constants to form the predicate list.  The other one is as long as the param is defined as the same variable they stay in scope.  This I know from the voodoo we pulled off with the Filter approach.  My only concern here is the chained OR having an issue and not compiling to native SQL.  I'll update as soon as I verify whether this works or not.

Comment: This is probably just a typo, but your executable expression contains `Func<Customer, bool>` while the rest of the example is generic `T`.

Comment: Yea typo in scrubbing it prior to posting.  It has an issue using Expression.Or against the Func<T,bool> type... which is irritating.

Answer (score 2):

As Ladislav says, you will need to dynamically generate your LINQ expressions.  Here is a simple example of a program that dynamically builds a predicate for a collection of integers:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        // Retreive your data source
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 };

        // Create a collection of predicates that you would like to chain together.
        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
        List<Expression> predicates = new List<Expression>();

        // x >= 50
        predicates.Add(Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(parameterExpression, Expression.Constant(50)));

        // x <= 20
        predicates.Add(Expression.LessThanOrEqual(parameterExpression, Expression.Constant(20)));

        // Build a single predicate by chaining individual predicates together in an OR fashion
        Expression whereFilter = Expression.Constant(false); // Use false a base expression in OR statements

        foreach (var predicate in predicates) {
            whereFilter = Expression.OrElse(whereFilter, predicate);
        }

        // Once the expressions have been chained, create a lambda to represent the whole predicate
        // x => (x >= 50) || (x <= 20)
        Expression<Func<int, bool>> whereLambda = 
            (Expression<Func<int, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(whereFilter, 
                                            new List<ParameterExpression>() { parameterExpression });

        // To use an expression directly, the datasource must be an IQueryable
        // Since I am using List<T> I must call AsQueryable.  This is not necessary
        // if your collection is already IQueryable, like in Entity Framework.
        var results = numbers.AsQueryable().Where(whereLambda);

    }
}
```

Essentially all I do here is create several boolean statments (x >= 50) and (x <= 20) and place them in a collection.  Then by looping through that collection, I take each statement and OR it to the last one.  The result is a series of boolean statements all linked together by OR.  I then wrap that statement in a Lambda expression so that it can be consumed by `IQueryable.Where` and pass it to my queryable collection.  The results are a filtered set of integers from my full set.

LINQ Expressions can be confusing to say the least, but they are incredibly powerful and worthwhile to know.  Please let me know if there's anything I can do to help make more sense of this example.

Comment: I agree, LINQ expressions have a fairly verbose and confusing syntax.  I'd say it's pretty simple as far as LINQ expressions go, just chaining a few simple boolean expressions together.

Comment: The only issue I have here is I'd like to pass in a list of Func<T,bool> or possibly Expression<Func<T,bool>> this solution means we have to build the expressions inline which will be a huge paradigm shift from how we are solving the filter issue.  The predicate builder we have in place works amazing and builds them at App Start... This solution requires reflection steps during execution and keeping the property names around along with the match value.  Which we already solved.  Any ideas on using this same approach only with Expression<Func<T,bool>>?