# Join a table to a List in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a List of `patient` objects. Each `patient` object has a firstname, lastname, and dob property. I'm needing to select all the rows from a `patients` table that have a matching object in the List. I need to match on firstname, lastname, AND dob. How can I do that in Entity Framework?

In SQL, i'd either create a temp table or a CTE and inner join the `patients` table to the CTE. I know i can't create temp tables or the like in Entity Framework so what other options do I have?

Curently, i just created a loop and select each row one at a time with a simple `.Where(x => x.NameFirst == patientDto.NameFirst && x.NameLast == patientDto.NameLast && x.DOB == patientDto.DOB)`

But obviously, that's terrible because it creates one database hit for each item in my List.

Comment: I think you can use a `SqlDbType.Structured` `SqlParameter` in a raw sql query. I don't think there's any `Linq` equivalent at this time. EF Core 5 is adding some additional TVP support, don't know it that helps though.

Comment: It should also be possible to use something like `.FromSqlInterpolated<Patient>($"select * from OpenJson({JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patientDto)}) with ( ... patient schema ...)")` to turn your client side list into an `IQueryable` which you can then join to. Probably as much effort as a table parameter.

Comment: If list is not so big, you can correct this answer and generate Expression Tree. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65048511/how-to-compare-generic-ef-core-entities-with-composite-keys/65049424#65049424

Comment: Neither CTEs nor temp tables help here. The only way to pass multiple items to a query is through a TVP or a lot of parameters. There's no simple way to write the SQL you want BUT EF Core 2+ has gotten rather fancy in the SQL it generates. For example, it uses `MERGE` and row constructors [to batch multiple INSERTs into a single statement](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/05/case-entity-framework-cores-odd-sql/). EF Core could use a similar technique for queries like yours (perhaps `patientList.Any(...)`?) but I haven't read anything relevant.

Comment: Or ... you could create a long `OR` expression comparing individual records. You can combine `AND` conditions with chained `Where`s, eg `query=query.Where()` but doing the same for `OR` requires creating the `Expression<>` in advance. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147521/chaining-or-conditions-in-ef-5-0) shows how to use [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to create expressions dynamically and combine them with `OR`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes! I think that's the only way to go here. if you write that as an answer, i'll mark it correct.